# Children’s book with a mouse called Nils

Tags: identification-request

All I can remember is one character, a mouse called Nils. I think he had a sword and was quite daring. And that’s it, I’m afraid- no idea of the plot, setting or any other details.
I probably read it in the 1960s but I’ve no idea when it was written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [***The Rescuers***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rescuers_(book)) (1959) by **Margery Sharp**.

- “a mouse called Nils”

  > **Nils** pulled his whiskers again. All **mice** have large families, and Nils was no better than any other man at keeping track of relations. ([p. 48](https://archive.org/details/isbn_0440773784/page/48/mode/2up))
- “I think he had a sword”

  > They left at once. (Nils just fetched his **cutlass** from the cloakroom, and he was ready too.) No one bothered to say good-by to them, in fact no one took any notice of them at all. ([p. 42](https://archive.org/details/isbn_0440773784/page/42/mode/2up))
- “and was quite daring”:

  > “Forgive me for joining you uninvited,” said Miss Bianca nervously, “but I am a delegate from the Prisoners’ Aid Society, seeking the **bravest mouse in Norway**, on behalf of a Norwegian poet imprisoned in our parts.” ([p. 35](https://archive.org/details/isbn_0440773784/page/34/mode/2up))

The book was made into a [1977 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rescuers) by Disney, but Nils does not appear: his role is merged with that of Bernard.